# AWS EC2-Windows Server cannot access outside network

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, windows-server

I Setup a AWS VPC
There are different subnet such as publics subnet and private subnet
My target is created a demo that Windows Server from private subnet access public internet through third party's EC2-Firewall in AWS-VPC

I create a EC2-Firewall with different interface into different subnet (with Allow all policy and allow interface ping)
I also create a EC2-windows server into private subnet, but it cannot access outside network

The issue observed:

1. EC2-windows can ping local network (/24) include firewall's interface
2. EC2-windows cannot access (web-browsing/ping) outside network
3. EC2-windows tracert 8.8.8.8, all response "* * * * request timeout" (default gateway cannot be shown too)
4. EC2-windows's Ethernet changed to DHCP or changed to static with firewall's interface IP as a default gateway, issue also occurred

Background Information:

1. Network ACLs is default setting (Allow All)
2. Security groups is allow all traffic in both direction
3. AWS subnet - Routing table with two record: Destination: VPC subnet, Target: Firewall's interface & Destination: 0.0.0.0/0, Target: Firewall's interface
4. Firewall's interface (same subnet) can ping & RDP to EC2-Windows
5. Firewall has no traffic record "source with EC2-windows, destination: outside network"
6. EC2-Windows's internal firewall is turn off

Any setting am I missing to check? what should I check to found the root cause related to AWS or Windows setting?

---

More information after Wireshark on Windows and package capture on firewall:

1. EC2-Windows sent the "ping 8.8.8.8" & "ping firewall's interface IP" to Firewall's Interface MAC address (shown in Wireshark)
2. Firewall's interface packet capture only "ping firewall's interface IP" be shown

Is it mean that AWS-VPC drop my outside traffic? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The root cause is "source/destination checks" of interface.
Since firewall will be able to send and receive traffic the source or destination is not itself when EC-Windows access outside network, AWS "source/destination checks" drop the packet of it.

After [Disable source/destination checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck), the issue is solved.